# How to change dimension of circles without scaling it?

Tags: mesh, objects, edit-mode, scale

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM6N7e-ZtVL0fwkwy3ro-GcIc6N8B31TkXccejEsRnbLwbFGzJ-_8oVY9HKey7FxQ?key=VjVvekRZbm5vQzdHUUhEQ0p5dWkySlVWOWJoLV9R

[image]

I want to make all circles with same thickness.

Also with different dimensions in circles but scaling changes the thickness of the circle.

Please provide me solution.

Comment: Your image is missing in the post. Please don't use photos of your screen, these have poor quality and are hard to read, take a screenshot instead

Comment: I find a literal screenshot once in a while refreshing and funny, actually.

Comment: To make screenshots in blender use Ctrl+F3 you can choose to save the Full Screen or just the active window.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this (it may not fit your workflow, though) is using an array modifier, fitting and following a circled curve (you can create a mesh circle, then convert it to curve with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in object mode):

First, you create a thin rectangle that will fit and then follow a curve, with modifiers. A thinner rectangle will give (as replied by array) higher resolution of the curved shape.

[image]

which produces this:

[image]

to make another circle, of the same width, duplicate both curve and rectangle, first:

[image]

then, scaling the curve, will keep the same width:

[image]

another bigger curve:

[image]

If you need to have just static meshes, you can then apply (in order) modifers... (maybe keep a "dynamic" copy to create new ones...)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To the right is a single nurbs circle which I opened with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in Edit Mode and turned into a half circle by deleting one control point.

To the left is a former mesh with three edges which I turned into a poly curve (again with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, just this time in Object Mode)

The left curve becomes the bevel object of the right curve. All one needs to do in order to change width or diameter of the circles is to move or scale the short curves to the left inside Edit Mode.

Comment: Can you please give more detailed answe....

Comment: "Make it more detailed" is not much of a motivation. So I slap you around a bit with the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/index.html